# JQuery how to match values of a text area to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know how to match values of an array to a textarea and if it does not match, it display a error message like " something wrong Are you sure about what you got into the text field? "

```js
function populateVariable(appLang){
  var selector = $('#field_new');
  var variables = [];
  // var exists;
  //input select
  selector.children('div').each(function(id, el) {
    $(el).children('.sub_block').each(function (id, el) {
      variables.push("$" + $(el).children('input')[0].value + "$ ")
    })
  });
  selector.children('div').each(function(id, el) {
    $(el).children('.option-item').each(function (id, el) {
      variables.push("$" + $(el).children('input')[0].value + "$ ")
    })
  });  
  $('#valueInput').text(appLang.getKey('valueInput') + variables);

}
```

```html
<div class="" id="formulaire-preview-text">
  <div id="valueInput"></div><br>
  <div id="inputs"></div><br>
  <textarea id="formulaire-preview-textarea" rows="12" cols="60"></textarea>
</div>
```

This function get all values of input and put them on an array "variables"

Comment: Do you want to store `textarea` content in array?

Comment: No, I want to match the values ​​that the user will put on the textarea against an array

Comment: What do you mean by match?

Comment: i want to check if the content of the textarea use all the values of my array else they return an error message

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.prototype.includes()

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(array1.includes(2));
// expected output: true

var pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'bat'];

console.log(pets.includes('cat'));
// expected output: true

console.log(pets.includes('at'));
// expected output: false
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes